# An Export error while trying to execute a few lines of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

While trying to execute this specific line of code, I'm getting an error saying the following:

export 'default' (imported as 'Contact') was not found in './pages/ContactUs' (possible exports: Contact)

I'm trying to add a button called next, so when I click on it it leads to a new tab.

```
import React from 'react';

export const Contact = () => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        const newWindow = window.open('/new-page', '_blank');
        newWindow.addEventListener('load', () => {
            newWindow.Contact();
        });
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Contact</button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown indeed has no *default* export.  It can be imported by name:

```
import { Contact } from './pages/ContactUs';
```

Or you can also make it a `default` export.  Personally I like to separate declarations from exports and put the latter at the end where possible for clarity:

```
const Contact = () => {
  //...
};

export default Contact;
```

After which you can then import that default:

```
import Contact from './pages/ContactUs';
```

Note that in this last case the name `Contact` doesn't *need* to match the exported name, since it's a `default` export.  But in general one almost always matches names anyway for clarity.

Comment: I tried that itself, and I still ended up getting the same error.

Comment: @Shashankgb: Can you include the updated code in the question?  Basically showing both the `ContactUs` file and the file that performs the `import`.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working after your suggestion. you have to import is as Contact and not { Contact } once you export it as default.